# Multi level sorting of numerical and string values

Tags: sorting, awk

I want to do a multi level sorting of floating values using `awk` on a data like below:

```
store:LA----------------400.68  
----pens----------------200.34  
--------reynolds--------110.34  
--------butterflow------90.00  
--------trimex----------NA  
----copies--------------110.34  
--------classmate-------110.34  
----pencil--------------90.00  
--------HB--------------44.5  
--------classmate-------45.5
```

The numerical value is the amount of available stock.

The sorted result should be like:

```
store:LA----------------400.68  
----pencil--------------90.00 
--------HB--------------44.5  
--------classmate-------45.5  
----copies--------------110.34  
--------classmate-------110.34  
----pens----------------200.34  
--------butterflow------90.00  
--------reynolds--------110.34  
--------trimex----------NA
```

In ascending order first based on the product and in product based on the brand with `NA` value in the last.

I tried picking up the values of `$2` first with respect to store (as there are multiple stores) then appending the value of product after the store value and in the last the value of brand and stored the same in an array.
It is something looks like:

```
400.68
400.68:200.34
400.68:200.34:110.34
400.68:200.34:90.00
400.68:200.34:NA
```

Using `asort` on this array is not displaying the required result:

```
{
      match($0, /^ */);
      offset = RLENGTH;
      if (offset == 1) { items[NR] = $2 }
      else if (offset > prev_ofst) { items[NR] = items[NR-1]":"$2 } 

      else if (offset < prev_ofst) {
         prev_item = items[NR-1];
         gsub("(\\:[^:]+\\:[^:]+)$", "", prev_item);
         items[NR] = prev_item":"$2;
      }
      else {
         prev_item = items[NR-1];
         gsub("(\\:[^:]+)$", "", prev_item);
         items[NR] = prev_item" "$2;
      }
      prev_ofst = offset;
      print items[NR];
}

END{
      asort(items);
      for (i = 1; i <= NR; i++) {
          gsub("[^:]+\\:", "", items[i]);
          print items[i];
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what `in product based on the brand with NA value in the last.` means (are you sorting based on brand which does not have an NA value in your sample input or are you sorting based on the number at the end of each line which does have an NA value?), but assuming that you have "pencil" and "copies" in the wrong order in your posted expected output, here's one way to do what I think you might want with GNU awk (which you're already using for `asort()`) for multi-dimensional arrays and sorted_in:

```
$ cat tst.awk
match($0,/^(-*)([^-]+)(-+)([^-]+)/,a) {
    offset = length(a[1])/4 + 1
    for (i=offset+1; i<=3; i++) {
        tags[i] = ""
    }
    tags[offset] = a[2]
    vals[tags[1]][tags[2]][tags[3]] = $0
}
END {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"
    for ( tag1 in vals ) {
        for ( tag2 in vals[tag1] ) {
            for ( tag3 in vals[tag1][tag2] ) {
                print vals[tag1][tag2][tag3]
            }
        }
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
store:LA----------------400.68
----copies--------------110.34
--------classmate-------110.34
----pencil--------------90.00
--------HB--------------44.5
--------classmate-------45.5
----pens----------------200.34
--------butterflow------90.00
--------reynolds--------110.34
--------trimex----------NA
```

Comment: thank you. the numerical value is the amount of product of respective brands. NA means that brand is not available, thus should come in the end. also as the values are to be sorted in increasing order  pencil should come before copies and then pens. and in pencil HB should come before classmate as the numerical value is less (which is as per your answer). also there are multiple stores adding a third level for sorting.